# igraph package in RStudio: Bipartite graph projection error

Tags: r, igraph, bipartite

In an attempt to learn the "nuts-and-bolts" of social network theory within the igraph package in R, I created a basic toy example of a bipartite graph of terror attacks during a single year of the Algerian Civil War. The vertices consist of terror perpetrators and targets, while the edges represent which group attacked which target.

I can plot the general unipartite graph of this relationship (as well as basic analyses of network centrality), but am having problems creating a bipartite projection of the network.

Per @GaborCsardi's suggestion, I've only loaded the igraph package into the global environment, as to ensure that the `sna` or `networks` packages do not conflict with the commands for igraph.

Nonetheless, the problem persists:

```
 library(igraph)

 perpetrator <- c("Algerian Islamic Extremists", 
             "Salafist Group for Preaching and Fighting (GSPC)", 
             "Salafist Group for Preaching and Fighting (GSPC)", 
             "Algerian Islamic Extremists", 
             "Salafist Group for Preaching and Fighting (GSPC)", 
             "Muslim Extremists",
             "Armed Islamic Group (GIA)",
             "Armed Islamic Group (GIA)",
             "Armed Islamic Group (GIA)",
             "Muslim Militants")

 target <- c("Police", "Military", "Terrorists/Non-state Militia", "Police",
             "Military", "Private Citizens & Property", 
             "Private Citizens & Property", "Private Citizens & Property", 
             "Private Citizens & Property", "Private Citizens & Property")

 dat <- cbind(perpetrator, target)

 net <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(dat)) 

 plot(net, main="Domestic Terrorism during the Algerian Civil War")

 V(net)$type <- FALSE

 V(net)$type[V(net)$name%in%dat$perpetrator] <- TRUE

 V(net)$type[V(net)$name%in%dat$target] <- TRUE

 bipartite.mapping(net)

 proj_net <- bipartite.projection(net, type=V(net)$type)
```

At which point, RStudio produces the following error:

```
 Error in .Call("R_igraph_bipartite_projection", graph, types, as.integer(probe1),  :  
 At bipartite.c:198 : Non-bipartite edge found in bipartite projection, Invalid value
```

Comment: First, your code doesn't run because you define `dat` as a matrix (using `cbind(...)`), and you cannot reference columns in a matrix using `$`. Use `dat<-data.frame(peretrator,target)`.

Comment: Second, you are setting `$type=TRUE` for all perpetrators, then setting `$type=TRUE` for all targets. So `V(net)$type` is TRUE always. What is the point of doing this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, `bipartite.mapping(...)`

> [decides whether the vertices of a network can be mapped to two vertex types in a way that no vertices of the same type are connected.](http://igraph.org/r/doc/is.bipartite.html/)

If it is possible to do this, then the `$type` element in the list returned by `bipartite.mapping(...)` identifies which sub-network each vertex belongs to (via `TRUE` or `FALSE`). Note that for your graph, there is more than one way to do this.

You seem to be (trying to) define your sub-networks yourself. Although in general, the sub-networks are not necessarily bipartite when you do this, in your case they are. So you can just use `bipartite.projection(...)` to divide `net` into the sub-networks, as follows:

```
V(net)$type <- FALSE
V(net)$type[V(net)$name%in%dat$perpetrator] <- TRUE
proj_net <- bipartite.projection(net)
```

`proj_net` is now a list with two elements, the subgraphs.

If you want to use `bipartite.mapping(...)` to identify the subnetworks, do it this way:

```
V(net)$type <- bipartite.mapping(net)$type
proj_net <- bipartite.projection(net)
set.seed(123)  # for reproducible plot
plot(net,vertex.color=ifelse(V(net)$type,"green","red"))
```

[image]

This does *not* group all the targets together, nor the perpetrators, but the red and green subnetworks *are*  bipartite.

Comment: Actually, my description of "bipartite" was incorrect. That has been corrected in the edit above to the first paragraph. The rest is correct.