# Bipartite graph projection error (igraph, RStudio)

Tags: r, igraph, bipartite

I am using [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) version 0.99.879 and the package [igraph](/questions/tagged/igraph) version 1.0.1. My question is closely related to this one on the same problem: [igraph package in RStudio: Bipartite graph projection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263227/igraph-package-in-rstudio-bipartite-graph-projection-error?rq=1) 
 However, my question is more related to the data structure. Here is a link to an example of the csv.file that I use: https://workupload.com/file/6qhyZqc and the following code:

```
# Start
set.seed(7)
setwd("C:/Users/Stefan/Desktop/")
data <- read.csv("example.csv", sep=";")
summary(data)

library(igraph)

## using subset function to select 2 variables
data_new <- subset(data, select=c(justification, claimant_function))
data_new

g <- graph.data.frame(data_new, directed = FALSE)
g

col <- c("steelblue1", "white")
shape <- c("circle", "square")

# creating bipartite network
V(g)$type <- FALSE
V(g)$type[V(g)$name %in% data_new[, 1]] <- TRUE
is.bipartite(g)
# TRUE

plot(g, layout = layout.kamada.kawai,
 vertex.shape = shape[as.numeric(V(g)$type) + 1],
 vertex.color = col[as.numeric(V(g)$type) + 1],
 edge.color = 'gray')

# bipartiate projection
one_mode_networks <- bipartite.projection(g)
# Error in .Call("R_igraph_bipartite_projection", graph, types, 
# as.integer(probe1),  : 
# At bipartite.c:198 : Non-bipartite edge found in bipartite projection, 
# Invalid value
```

Everything works out except the projection command. So,the code is not the problem. Perhaps the mistake/problem might be in the data itself. Since I am working with the data already quite a while, I think, I am professionally blinkered. It would be great if someone else could have a look at the posted example data and could give suggestions what the issue might be. 
 Any help is highly welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My hunch is that you have a tie between two nodes of the same affiliation. A bit of searching and indeed this is the case.

Notice that you have the string 'other' in *both* columns of `data_new`:

```
data_new[which(data_new[,1] %in% data_new[,2]),1]
[1] "other"
```

`igraph` reads the string as the one node in the network. `V(g)$type[V(g)$name %in% data_new[, 1]] <- TRUE` gives it a value of `TRUE` for its `type`.

We can see which tie connects two vertices whose `type == 'TRUE'`:

```
> i <- which(V(g)$type[match(ends(g,1:ecount(g))[,1],V(g)$name)] == V(g)$type[match(ends(g,1:ecount(g))[,2],V(g)$name)])
> ends(g, i)
     [,1]                 [,2]   
[1,] "financial solidity" "other"
```

The 12th edge, both vertices have `type==TRUE`.

Simply revalue the strings so that they are not equal and everything runs smoothly.

```
data_new <- subset(data, select=c(justification, claimant_function))
data_new[which(data_new[,1]=="other"),1] <- "other just"
data_new[which(data_new[,2]=="other"),2] <- "other claim"

g <- graph.data.frame(data_new, directed = FALSE)

# creating bipartite network
V(g)$type <- FALSE
V(g)$type[V(g)$name %in% data_new[, 1]] <- TRUE
is.bipartite(g)

one_mode_networks <- bipartite_projection(g)
```

Check:

```
> one_mode_networks
$proj1
IGRAPH UNW- 16 72 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
 [1] business        --expert/scientist       business        --public figure         
 [3] business        --media/journalist       business        --citizen               
 [5] business        --legislative            business        --ECB                   
 [7] government      --media/journalist       government      --expert/scientist      
 [9] government      --other claim            government      --legislative           
[11] government      --ECB                    government      --European Commission   
[13] government      --other politician/party government      --European Parliament   
[15] government      --citizen                government      --European Council      
+ ... omitted several edges

$proj2
IGRAPH UNW- 16 83 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
 [1] political solidarity--monetary solidarity  political solidarity--financial solidity  
 [3] political solidarity--no justification     political solidarity--cultural solidarity 
 [5] political solidarity--sovereignty          political solidarity--self interest       
 [7] political solidarity--economic solidarity  political solidarity--human solidarity    
 [9] financial solidity  --social solidarity    financial solidity  --misuse of solidarity
[11] financial solidity  --economic solidarity  financial solidity  --cultural solidarity 
[13] financial solidity  --self interest        financial solidity  --legal regulations   
[15] financial solidity  --necessity            financial solidity  --conditionally       
+ ... omitted several edges
```

Comment: Great. Your answer was exactly what I was looking for (and pointed me towards other 'coding similarities' in the rest of the dataset). Thank you so much!

Comment: The value of such errors in exposing underlying problems in our datasets cannot be overstated!